# PyCharm won't install pycurl macOS High Sierra

Tags: python, pycharm, pycurl

I am trying to get pycurl to install on PyCharm for MacOS High Sierra, but I keep getting this error:

```
__main__.ConfigurationError: 
Curl is configured to use SSL, but we have not been able to determine
which SSL backend it is using. 
Please see PycURL documentation for how to specify the SSL backend manually.
```

I am able to get pycurl to install in terminal with the commands

```
PYCURL_SSL_LIBRARY=openssl 
LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib" 
CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include" 
pip install --no-cache-dir pycurl
```

and

```
pip install 
    --no-cache-dir 
    --compile
    --ignore-installed 
    --install-option="--with-openssl" 
    --user pycurl
```

However, when trying to run in PyCharm, it doesn't recognize that pycurl is installed unless I install it through PyCharm. PyCharm only gives me the option to add options to the `pip install` command, so the first solution doesn't work. The second solution does not work because PyCharm's venv does not allow the `--self` option. When I try to run without this option, I get the same error I would get with no options.